# Can a comment be accepted as an answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it possible to accept a comment as an answer?

I often see questions which can be answered in a comment. They mostly come from newcomers and sometimes from old members (like me) as well. For me it happens because I don't know some options or proper syntax (learning everyday). If just a small hint in comment solves my problem, I would prefer to accept it as an answer and thus to offer the commenter some credits.

Comment: You can either prompt the user to post his/her comment as an answer, or if the user seems to not have been active for quite a while, you can post an answer summarizing the contents of the comment. (Setting it CW is optional, but it is sometimes done.)

Comment: Related: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1244/18476

Comment: [The answers here are in comments. That cracks me up.]